# search in the table is not working when search data is made blank in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a mini-app that consists of a search bar and a table with data. The data is searchable using the search bar. I am using lodash debounce to filter the table data when a user enters something in the search bar. So far so good. The problem arises when the search word is erased by pressing the backspace. I want the table to restore the initial data when no input is entered or input is erased.

```
type IType = {company: string, city: string, domain: string}

export const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<string>('');
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<IType[]>(data);

    const filterTable = ()=>{
        const filteredData = tableData.filter((data)=>data.company.toLowerCase().includes(userInput)
         || data.city.toLowerCase().includes(userInput)
         || data.domain.toLowerCase().includes(userInput));
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('filteredData', filteredData);
        filteredData.length === data.length ?  setTableData([...data]) : setTableData([...filteredData]);
    };

    const debouncedData = useCallback(debounce(filterTable, 1000), [userInput]);

    useEffect(() => {
        debouncedData();
    }, [userInput]);

    const onChangeHandler:
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void = (event) => setUserInput(event.target.value);


    return (
        <div style={mainWrapper}>
            <SearchBar userInput={userInput} onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler} />
            <Table tableData={tableData}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

;

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `conditional rendering`.

If the search input is empty string, just display the original `data` and not the computed `tableData`.

```
type IType = {company: string, city: string, domain: string}

export const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<string>('');
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<IType[]>(data);

    const filterTable = ()=>{
        const filteredData = tableData.filter((data)=>data.company.toLowerCase().includes(userInput)
         || data.city.toLowerCase().includes(userInput)
         || data.domain.toLowerCase().includes(userInput));
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('filteredData', filteredData);
        filteredData.length === data.length ?  setTableData([...data]) : setTableData([...filteredData]);
    };

    const debouncedData = useCallback(debounce(filterTable, 1000), [userInput]);

    useEffect(() => {
        debouncedData();
    }, [userInput]);

    const onChangeHandler:
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void = (event) => setUserInput(event.target.value);


    return (
        <div style={mainWrapper}>
            <SearchBar userInput={userInput} onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler} />
            <Table tableData={userInput === "" ? data : tableData}/>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-lichterman-dgsqf?file=/src/index.tsx.  it does not work in the second search.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-lichterman-dgsqf?file=/src/index.tsx.  it does not work in the second search. In the first search, tableData has only one matching entry left. When search for the second item, it try to lookup in the table with one left over entry.

Comment: @ryan what do you mean by does not work. it throws error or ?? and what do you mean by search for the second item? i thought the input was for single search?

Comment: @ryan ahhh i get it, it's because your filterTable function is searching inside the resulted `tableData` and not the original `data`. i've fixed your code here with also removing warnings and fix the potential bug when searching item is not found in Table component. https://codesandbox.io/s/search-table-jk9qv?file=/src/components/App/index.tsx

Comment: Thank you. I realised the mistake i was doing in the code.

Comment: Can you please explain me following code? Object.keys(
                    tableData?.[0] ?? { company: '', city: '', domain: '' }
                )

Comment: i am aware of the optional chaining but not sure what the ?? operator is doing?

Comment: it's called nullish coalescing operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator basically it checks if something is null or undefined ONLY .... normal logical OR operator ( || ) checks if something is falsy e.g, false(boolean), 0 , ""(empty string),  including null and undefined..